# Avoiding UNION in select query

Tags: sql, union

I am having the below SQL for a report query, where I have to list out all birthdays and anniversaries between a given time frame. Is there a better way to do this avoiding the UNION and  with SELECT - DISTINCT ?
I have changed this to use UNION ALL, since the data is already distinct.

Note that we can have anniversaries and birthdays both in the same time frame.

```
SELECT  
    gpms.[birthdate]          AS [Date],
    'Birthday'                AS [Event], 
    gpms.[name]               AS [Name], 
    gpms.[email]              AS [Email],     
    gpms.[address]            AS [Address],   
FROM PERSONDETAILS gpms
JOIN @selectedpersons sgf ON sgf.[account] = gpms.[account]
WHERE DATEADD(year,DATEDIFF(YEAR, birthdate, @p_StartDate),birthdate) BETWEEN @p_StartDate AND @p_endDate
   OR DATEADD(year,DATEDIFF(YEAR, birthdate, @p_endDate  ),birthdate) BETWEEN @p_StartDate AND @p_endDate
UNION 
SELECT 
    gpms.[birthdate]          AS [Date],
    'Birthday'                AS [Event], 
    gpms.[name]               AS [Name], 
    gpms.[email]              AS [Email],     
    gpms.[address]            AS [Address],   
FROM PERSONDETAILS gpms
JOIN @selectedpersons sgf ON sgf.[account] = gpms.[account] 
WHERE DATEADD(year,DATEDIFF(YEAR, Anniversary, @p_StartDate),Anniversary) BETWEEN @p_StartDate AND @p_endDate
   OR DATEADD(year,DATEDIFF(YEAR, Anniversary, @p_endDate  ),Anniversary) BETWEEN @p_StartDate AND @p_endDate
```

Comment: the only thing different between the two selects is the where clause?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, only the where clause is different, right? So why don't you merge the condition using `OR`

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but wouldn't `WHERE [birthdate] BETWEEN @p_StartDate AND @p_endDate` be easier then the `DATEADD(...DATEDIFF(...))` thing you're doing?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT
gpms.[birthdate]          AS [Date],
'Birthday'                AS [Event], 
gpms.[name]               AS [Name], 
gpms.[email]              AS [Email],     
gpms.[address]            AS [Address],   
FROM PERSONDETAILS gpms
JOIN @selectedpersons sgf  ON sgf.[account] = gpms.[account]    
WHERE DATEADD(year,DATEDIFF(YEAR, birthdate, @p_StartDate),birthdate) BETWEEN @p_StartDate AND @p_endDate
OR DATEADD(year,DATEDIFF(YEAR, birthdate, @p_endDate),birthdate) BETWEEN @p_StartDate AND @p_endDate
OR DATEADD(year,DATEDIFF(YEAR, Anniversary, @p_StartDate),Anniversary) BETWEEN @p_StartDate AND @p_endDate
OR DATEADD(year,DATEDIFF(YEAR, Anniversary, @p_endDate),Anniversary) BETWEEN @p_StartDate AND @p_endDate
```